# D3.js: Animating a bezier curve

Tags: javascript, d3.js, workflow

I'm using the following code to generate a `bezier curve` for a workflow design:

```
    group.append("svg:path")
  .attr("d","m " +(300*k) +",0 q "+(z*150)+",-300,"+z*300+", 0")
      .attr("fill","blue")
  .style("stroke", "blue").attr("stroke-width",2)
  .attr("marker-end", "url(#arrow)").attr("fill","none").append("text");
```

I want to achieve [this animation](http://bl.ocks.org/duopixel/4063326) in the curve. Any suggestion might help.

Comment: Have you tried using the same approach as in the example you've linked to?

Answer (score 0):

[Here is an example](http://www.jasondavies.com/animated-bezier/) of animated Bezier curves. You can inspect the code that he is using on that page, but, basically the trick is as they say...

> For a second-order or quadratic Bézier curve, first we find two intermediate points that are *t* along the lines between the three control points. Then we perform the same interpolation step again and find another point that is *t* along the line between those two intermediate points. Plotting this last point yields a quadratic Bézier curve. The same steps can be repeated for higher orders.

Comment: Oddly I can't comment on other folks comments until I have 50 reputation.... In any event the OP example isn't using a Bezier curve it is using Cardinal spline. Maybe some of the other [interpolate choices](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#line_interpolate) you might be able to approximate the effect you want, but they example I gave gives a good explanation of how to animate a Bezier.